# Compare individual columns with reference column in pandas after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `dat` that looks like following:

[image]

I want to individually compare `A` and `B` with Ground_Truth "after" grouping by C. I want to use `dat.apply()` function. If I dont do  `dat.groupby('C')`, and simply do `dat.apply()`, I get individual series `A`, `B`, `C` to compare against. However, if I do `dat.groupby('C').apply()`, I get all groupped dataframe inside `apply()` function. Is there a way to handle this scenario better way?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: You must provide a [mre], images of data are not acceptable

Comment: @Ben.T the expected output is average of the difference between `Ground_Truth` individually with `A` and `B`, based on groupped `C`. But that is easier if I am able to find out how make operation of  `A` and `B` with `Ground_Truth` after groupping by `C`